# Windows 7 Resolution Error

Tags: windows-7, resolution

After working in Windows 7 for about three months, it went strange. I had restarted my system manually since it hang and from the next run, the screen became smaller. Thought in the resolution, it showed my correct resolution 1600x900 but there are resolutions unsupported by my monitor also. The screen only displays in the middle half.

I had searched in the display properties and checked to display only supported resolutions. Still the same.

How can I fix it?

Comment: your issue sounds like screen size rather than resolution (which is why it appears smaller but at the same res). does your driver or monitor have screen size settings? you may be able to resize the screen to fill your monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to this problem after reading my monitor manual. Disabling Aspect Ratio got rid of this.